# Light novel where people go to different worlds and get three classes; main character befriends a dragon

Tags: story-identification, novel

I started reading this a while ago, and I can only remember parts, all from the beginning:

1. The everyone gets the ability to go to a different world where they level up in a game like way
2. Everyone gets a weapon or similar to start of with
3. Everyone gets three different classes to chose from. The one the MC picks let's him insert his power/mana/energy into it and gets control over it, he first uses this on a broad sword.
4. He befriends a young dragon through giving him his phone with a mobile game the young dragon likes
5. At first the MC is travelling with his mom, his childhood friend and the friends family + the family's body guards
6. Everyone goes through a class progression his has something to do with taking control of a hammer as fast as possible.

Edit: it also might've been a webnovel.

Comment: It sounds like the author has a trope dartboard

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When (year) was "a while ago?"

Comment: Like a year ago which probably isn't a while but it's far enough for my memory to go.